# For some reason unity crashes with this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d

Basically, I have this thing in my game to switch the biome of a certain chunk.
The problem with it is it prevents the game from ever running (even in the inspector)

```
if(obj.name == "Dirt" && Atlas.Dirt != null)
            {
                gen.MakeTile(Mathf.RoundToInt(trans.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(trans.position.y), Atlas.Dirt.placableVariant, trans.rotation.z, Atlas.Dirt.MapColor, true);
                Destroy(obj);
            }
```

That's the bit that crashes everything
and this makes tile:

```
public void MakeTile(int x, int y, GameObject Object, float RotationalChange, Color MapColor, bool AddToArray)
    {
        float ChunkCoord = (Mathf.Round(x / chunkWidth) * chunkWidth);
        ChunkCoord /= chunkWidth;

        GameObject NewTile = Instantiate(Object, new Vector3Int(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity, Chunks[(int)ChunkCoord].transform);
        NewTile.name = Object.name;

        FireBlockUpdate();

        if(AddToArray)
            Blocks[x, y] = NewTile;

        NewTile.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, RotationalChange);
        texture.SetPixel(x, y, MapColor);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get some sort of error? What is it? More details please.

Comment: The game takes too long to load so i dont know if i get any error, ive waited a max of 15 mins with not even a frame loaded

Comment: Sounds like a good time to learn to use the debugger.

Comment: all the values appear to be correct and as wanted but still the game indefinitely loads